# Participle classes

Tags: word-usage

This both sentences are present participles

What is the difference between one is joining a coma and the other is joining (and) for example

> She heard the news and fainted.

> Hearing the news, she fainted.

Is joining (and) and the other is coma e.g

> When I turned off the radio, I left the house.

> Turning off the radio, I left the house

Why second sentence we can use ( when) but the frist sentence we can't use

Can we say: when/upon hearing the news, she fainted. Please don't close my comment i want to know how enlish grammar working more

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326784/participle-classes#comment616178_326784) user [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) offered this answer:

> Those commas (which are all to a greater or lesser extent optional) only exist in order to reflect pauses in the spoken versions. Note that clauses like *when/upon hearing the news* (with optional initial preposition) are *parenthetical adverbial elements* (the utterance would still be syntactically valid without them). In general, such adverbial clauses can go before or after the primary assertion, and this may affect whether one chooses to separate the adverbial element from the main clause by use of a pause/comma.

Answer (score 0):

The sentences:

> (1A) She heard the news and fainted.

> (!B) Hearing the news, she fainted.

have essentially the same meaning. (1B) emphasizes that the faint came directly on hearing the news, but that is fairly clear from (1A) also. Otherwise the difference  is only a matter of style. There are often several different ways to express an idea in English.

The sentences:

> (2A) When I turned off the radio, I left the house.

> (2B) Turning off the radio, I left the house.

also have pretty much the same meaning.

In (2B) the use of the present participle "*turning off*"  indicates that the radio was turned off at the same tame as the speaker left the house. In (2A) that information is conveyed by the word "*when*". Thus the word  "*when*" is not needed in (2B). It would be possible to write a sentence that included both "when" and "turning off", but it would not have the same meaning.

I do not agree with user FumbleFingers that the commas in these sentences serve **only** to mark the locations of pauses in the spoken versions. They also serve to separate the clauses. In some cases such commas also serve to help avoid ambiguity, although there is not much if any possible ambiguity in these examples.

---

There are several errors in the question, not relates to the sentences asked about:

- "*This both sentences*" is not correct. "Both of these sentences would be correct.
- The sentences **use** participles, it is not correct to say that they **are** participles.
- "*one is joining a coma*" is not correct. It should be something like "one is joining two clauses **using** a comma"
- The whole sentence "*What is the difference between one is joining a coma and the other is joining (and)*" should be something more like "What is the difference between a sentence that joins two clauses using a comma, and one that joins clauses using *and*"?.
- "*Why second sentence we can use ( when) but the frist sentence we can't use*" should be something like "Why can we use *when* in the first sentence, but in the second sentence we can't [use when]?"

Comment: I'd say that 'When I turned off the radio, I left the house' sounds unnatural (though one could probably find justifying context). Sequentiality ('When I had turned off the radio, I left the house') (or indeed 2B may carry this sense) rather than synchronicity seems far more likely. // 1A/B carry a causal relationship.